# SQL: Select Top 3 Records + Sum of Quantity

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

I would like to display the top 3 records from the existing **Orders** table. In order to accomplish this, I need to calculate the sum of each product's quantity.

Existing Records:

```
OrderNo     ProductID     Quantity
1           1             50
1           2             30
1           3             20
2           2             30
3           1             100
3           4             50
4           1             20
4           5             10
5           2             10
```

Expected Output

```
ProductID     Quantity
1             170
2             70
4             50
```

Comment: how and why the expected output come from current table?

Comment: I think for ProductID = 1, Quantity should be 170 **:)**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to `SUM` and then `ORDER BY` this summary value:

```
SELECT TOP 3 ProductID, SUM(Quantity) as qSum
FROM Table
GROUP BY ProductID
ORDER BY qSum DESC
```

Comment: Got the same answer except for the ORDER BY qSum. Thank you.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT TOP 3 ProductID, SUM(Quantity) as SUMQUANTITY
FROM Table1
GROUP BY ProductID
ORDER BY SUMQUANTITY desc
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/211a2/3)