# Access 2010 SQL select top with an additional field

Tags: sql, select, subquery, grouping, ms-access-2010

This gives me the top 5 category/year combinations by spending:

```
SELECT TOP 3 [Category],
             SUM([Spending]),
             Year
FROM Data
GROUP BY [Category], [Year]
;
```

I would like to look at the overall top 5 categories for every year.

e.g. If the top spending categories over the 3 year period are A,B,C (but not D) I would like to output this:

```
  Category   Total Spending   Year
  A          123              1  
  A          321              2
  A          987              3
  B          798              1
  B          465              2 
  B          153              3
  C          654              1
  C          486              2
  C          759              3
```

This is solved here, but only with two fields- [SQL: Select Top 3 Records + Sum of Quantity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17985491/sql-select-top-3-records-sum-of-quantity)

Comment: You want to select the top 5 categories per year, for a 3 years period?

Comment: No, I want the top 5 categories over the entire 3 year period, followed each year. So if a category was not a top 3 spender in one year, but overall it was a top spender, I still want to see it for every year.  ---But to be honest, it would additionally be helpful to me to know how to do what you mentioned.

Comment: Ok, i put my query in the answer, tell me if it fit you request.

Answer (score 1):

Try in this way:

```
SELECT [Category], SUM([Spending]) as TotalSpending, Year
FROM Data
WHERE Year IN (SELECT TOP 5 Year FROM Data ORDER BY Year DESC)
GROUP BY [Category], [Year]
ORDER BY SUM([Spending])  DESC, [Year] DESC
```

Comment: When I use exactly this code, I am asked to 'Enter Parameter Value' for TotalSpending. If I click cancel, or use the code without TotalSpending, I get 5 records in total in the output. In the case of my data, they are all for the most recent year, 2013. I want to see these spending totals for these categories for each and every year in my data. So since my data goes back to 2007 there should be 7yrs* 5 categories = 35 records

Comment: I changed the query, cause an error for MS ACCESS in the order by clause. Try this.

Comment: In Access this shows the same result as in my first code above- the top five year/category combinations. Again still only 5 total records, not 35.

Comment: I Modified the query with a where clause the limit the data to the last 3 years

Comment: This won't run in my version of Access 2010, it took over an hour to process. Have you tried it? Also, won't this just show me all categories for the past three years?